# Using an external DLL in .NET Core

Tags: .net, .net-core

I would like to create a .NET Core program that uses an external DLL for some processing tasks.

This external DLL to be used is an external and commercial component that we do not control. As of right now, the vendor does not provide a .NET Standard compatible version.

How can I start using this DLL in my application? 
The Microsoft documentation is not clear on this.

Can I wrap this DLL in a .NET standard project?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

External dependencies (dlls) can be either of third-party or your own. Now when it comes to third party, then look for the version of *.NET Standard* it support. If you are developing your own re-usable component then create a class library that target a specific *.NET Standard.* You may be able to use and refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library) matrix to build your component which has maximum reach with expected support.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In my case, the DLL to be used is an external and commercial component that we do not control. As of right now, the vendor does not provide a .NET Standard compatible version. So do I wait for the vendor to provide such a version, or is there an alternative way to wrap this DLL in .NET standard project?

Comment: You can export old version to .net core with help of project analyser. But in your case you don't have the source code. So I don't think this is possible unless they re-build their projects on any specific standard.

Answer (score 0):

If you wait for .NET Core 2.0 (as of april 2017, a preview tooling of 2.0 + 2.0 tools - "SDK" - should be available soon), you can directly use .net framework (non-".NET Standard") DLLs in .net core applications using:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="path\to\the.dll" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Note that even though it may build, the DLL might still use APIs that aren't available on .net core, such as System.Configuration or System.Web. This will result in a runtime error in which case you might need to add NuGet packages or contact the vendor of the library to create a .net core / .net standard compatible version (preferable a NuGet package).